# How to get adminhtml session data from the storefront?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, session, store-view

I have been trying to get adminhtml session by DI  **Magento\Backend\Model\Session** but I get nothing.

Is it possible to get adminhtml session information from the storefront and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you can set or get the data which you want.

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Model;

class MyCustomClass
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Session
     */
    protected $backendSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Model\Context
     */
    protected $context;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Session $backendSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
    ) {
        $this->backendSession = $backendSession;
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function onSalesOrderCreditmemoRegisterBefore($observer)
    {
         $this->backendSession->setVmaId('TestingVarialble');
         echo $this->backendSession->getVmaId();
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean I need to have information about the currently logined administrator on the storefront. Anyway your solution does not work cause  if I set some values from adminhtml controller to backend session, I still cannot get that value from backend session on front conrtroller.

Comment: You can set this data in table or cookie as well.

Comment: It is not right way. So I am interesting in only my question.

Comment: @ManishGoswami https://stackoverflow.com/a/65968400/3690413